# Sinusoidal function from $4$ knowns

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am trying to find out what sinusoidal function is represented by a minimum of $(0, -10)$ and a maximum of $(2, -4)$

I know that the period is $4$ and that the midpoint would be $(1, -7)$ but that is it.

How am I supposed to figure out from a period of $4$, a midpoint of $(1, -7)$, a minimum of $(0, -10)$ and a maximum of $(2, -4)$ what the function is? How am I even supposed to know whether it is sine or cosine since both functions could exist with these known data(I know that because cosine is just sine + pi/2).

Comment: The period can't be 2 if it goes from min to max in 2 units.

Comment: I edited it so that the period is 4 instead of 2

Comment: Because of what you noted about sine and cosine, it could be either. $a*\cos(bx+c)+d$ is the same bunch of functions as $a*\sin (bx+c)+d$

Comment: But the question is asking me for a single formula, not a bunch of formulas.

Comment: then pick whichever single formula is easiest for you to find. You can get an answer by starting with sine or cosine, and assuming that the coefficient of the trig function $a$ is positive or negative. Try manipulating the variables in my other comment to see if you can adjust the locations of the trough and peak to be what you want, and edit your question with your attempts/observations if you don't get all the way there.